# Dao Registry refactoring

Tags: java, spring

Using the generic dao pattern, I define the generic interface:

```
public interface GenericDao<T extends DataObject, ID extends Serializable> {
    T save(T t);
    void delete(ID id);
    T findById(ID id);
    Class<T> getPersistentClass();
}
```

I then implemented an default GenericDaoImpl implementation to perform these functions with the following constructor:

```
public GenericDaoImpl(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.persistentClass = clazz;
    DaoRegistry.getInstance().register(clazz, this);
}
```

The point of the DaoRegistry is to look up a Dao by the class associating to it.  This allows me to extend GenericDaoImpl and overwrite methods for objects that requires special handling:

```
DaoRegistry.getInstance().getDao(someClass.getClass()).save(someClass);
```

While it works, there are a few things that I don't like about it:

- DaoRegistry is an singleton
- The logic of calling save is complicated

Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit**
I am not looking to debate whether Singleton is an [anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126158/what-is-your-favorite-anti-pattern) or not.

Comment: If you don't like things being singletons, then Spring is going to make you very unhappy.

Comment: Spring bean differ from the singleton pattern, but that's another argument all together =)

Comment: No they don't. A singleton is unique within a scope, per definition. The difference lies only in the scope. Classic singleton = ClassLoader, Spring Bean = Application. The concept remains the same.

Comment: Take a look at here: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects

Comment: I'd say the issue is not whether singleton is the antipattern here. I'd rather be concerned of the Service Locator pattern breaking the Inversion of Control pattern if I were you..

Comment: @ortang: I also thought about using the pattern mentioned in your link.  However, I don't like the idea of having to add a new getDaoXYZ method to the factory each time a new dao is needed.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd:Hence I am asking if there is a better way.  I'd hate to have to inject a new Dao to my service layer each time for classes that requires special handling.

Comment: A Singleton is a Pattern, the fact that a class has only one instance, should not called Singleton, but sometimes it is. -- So I guess you speek of different concepts. Spring Beans has only one instance, but they do not implement the Singleton pattern -- And the discussion about how bad a Singleton Pattern is are related to the Pattern, not to the fact that there is only one instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be better to use instance of DaoRegistry instead of static methods. It would make it more manageable for test configurations. You could implement it as

```
@Component("daoRegistry")
public class DaoRegistry {
  @Autowired
  private List<GenericDao> customDaos;

  private GenericDao defaultDao = new GenericDaoImpl();

  public <T> T getDao(Class<T> clazz) {
    // search customDaos for matching clazz, return default dao otherwise
  }
}
```

Also you could add save method to it and rename accordingly. All customised daos should be available as beans.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what is your problem with DaoRegistry being singleton?

Anyway, you could have an abstract base class for your entities that'd implement save like this

```
public T save(){
    DaoRegistry.getInstance().getDao(this.getClass()).save(this);
}
```

then you could simply call `someEntity.save()`

Or it may be more straightforward if the entity classes itself implemented the whole `GenericDao` interface (save, delete and find methods), so the contents of your `GenericDaoImpl` would be in the base class of your entities.

Comment: Hmm that's a thought.  This will bring it to something close to ActiveRecord.  Anyone care to comment if this is any downside to doing this?

Comment: Pro: it's very handy. Con: it's awful. Entities should not have any idea where, how and if they are stored anywhere.

Comment: "Entities should not have any idea where, how and if they are stored anywhere."
I Agree.